# Java ListCellRenderer and JList: handle selection

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I got stuck with a project i have to do at school.

i was trying to create a custom `JList` for a "simple" UI: the use case should be displaying a list of orders and the user should be able to select one and set if read/done by pressing two buttons (read and done) which acts also as "unsetters" (i'm using 2 boolean in class Order which keep going trough t,f,t,f...). Once pressed Done, the selected row should turn green (and staying permanently on that color) until "Done" button is again pressed on that row (=unset). Same thing of button "Read" which should turn selected row permanently yellow relating to "is_read" flag in class Order.

After reading some related posts, I wrote this custom `ListCellRenderer`:

```
public class CookListCellRender extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Order>{

public CookListCellRender(){
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Order> list, Order value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setText(value.getNameEl());
    list.setVisibleRowCount(30);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.ITALIC,17));

    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        setBackground(getBackground());
        setForeground(getForeground());
    }

    if(value.getOrderRead()){
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }else{
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    if(value.getOrderDone()){
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }else{
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    return this;
}

}
```

My problem is, once running my test file, everything pops up properly but when I select a row and I press one of those 2 buttons nothing happens until I select a new row: then keeps turning green or yellow (depending by the button I pressed) the color of the row I'm selecting.

I'm pretty sure this is a problem related to my custom cell renderer, also because I'm still learning how to use it and I started getting pretty confused.

Here is the rest of my relevant code related to the UI, maybe it's useful. Buttons and their listeners are in a separate class (a custom `JPanel`), but those are working fine, so...

Class `InitGraphics` (directly called by my test class):

```
public class InitGraphics {

Cook c;
JList list;

public InitGraphics(Cook cuoco){
    c=cuoco;
    initUi();
  }

private void initUi() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cucina");
    list =new JList(c.getOrdersCopy().toArray());
    list.setCellRenderer(new CookListCellRender());
    JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane(list);
    panel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(c.getOrdersCopy(),list);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest, no I **urge** you to create and post a valid [sscce](http://sscce.org) if you need serious and prompt help. Otherwise your code is close to useless to us and limits our ability to understand your problem.

Comment: For example: none of us can compile nor run this code. We don't want to see your  whole program or wade through a large amount of code not relevant to the problem, but if you could condense your code to the smallest example that compiles and runs for us unmodified, that shows us your problem, and that is small enough to post here with your question as code-formatted text, we would likely be able to solve your issue quite quickly.

Comment: I'm sorry, bad internet connection here. Btw i never heard before about sscce but i tried to... well i got 140 lines code, wich I don't think is very suitable but does his job. Not being a "java veteran" i tried my best, I leave it here with a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QUP0v8ke) just not to edit the already posted code

Comment: I gave you two SSCCE's with my answer below. Please go through the [help] section on asking questions -- no links to code please, only code posted here. But again, please check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is killing you:

```
    } else {
        setBackground(getBackground());
        setForeground(getForeground());
    }
```

It doesn't change anything at all. I think that you want:

```
    } else {
        setBackground(null);
        setForeground(null);
    }
```

Note that to do any work at all on this code, I had to create my own [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InitGraphics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final DefaultListModel<Order> orderModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("One"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Two"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Three"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Four"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Five"));

            JList<Order> orderList = new JList<>(orderModel);
            orderList.setCellRenderer(new CookListCellRender());

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JScrollPane(orderList));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
        });
    }
}

class CookListCellRender extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Order> {

    public CookListCellRender() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Order> list, Order value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setText(value.getNameEl());
        list.setVisibleRowCount(30);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 17));

        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            // TODO: fix!
            // setBackground(getBackground());
            // setForeground(getForeground());
            setBackground(null);
            setForeground(null);
        }

        if (value.getOrderRead()) {
            setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        if (value.getOrderDone()) {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return this;
    }

}

class Order {

    private String nameE1;
    private boolean orderDone;
    private boolean orderRead;

    public Order(String nameE1) {
        this.nameE1 = nameE1;
    }

    public String getNameEl() {
        return nameE1;
    }

    public boolean getOrderDone() {
        return orderDone;
    }

    public boolean getOrderRead() {
        return orderRead;
    }

    public void setOrderDone(boolean orderDone) {
        this.orderDone = orderDone;
    }

    public void setOrderRead(boolean orderRead) {
        this.orderRead = orderRead;
    }

}
```

In the future, please do this work for us, since you're the one asking for help, and we're volunteers.

Also this:

```
    list.setVisibleRowCount(30);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Never do this sort of thing from within a renderer. This code should go where you create the JList, not in the renderer.

Here's my latest SSCCE, one that includes clear/read/done buttons

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class InitGraphics {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final DefaultListModel<Order> orderModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("One"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Two"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Three"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Four"));
            orderModel.addElement(new Order("Five"));

            final JList<Order> orderList = new JList<>(orderModel);
            orderList.setCellRenderer(new CookListCellRender());
            orderList.setVisibleRowCount(5);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            // panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
            panel.add(new JScrollPane(orderList));

            panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Read") {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    List<Order> selectedOrders = orderList.getSelectedValuesList();
                    for (Order order : selectedOrders) {
                        order.setOrderRead(true);
                    }
                    orderList.repaint();
                }
            }));
            panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Done") {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    List<Order> selectedOrders = orderList.getSelectedValuesList();
                    for (Order order : selectedOrders) {
                        order.setOrderDone(true);
                    }
                    orderList.repaint();
                }
            }));
            panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Clear") {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < orderModel.size(); i++) {
                        orderModel.getElementAt(i).setOrderDone(false);
                        orderModel.getElementAt(i).setOrderRead(false);
                    }
                    orderList.repaint();
                }
            }));


            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test List");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CookListCellRender extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Order> {

    public CookListCellRender() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Order> list, Order value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        // setOpaque(true); // !! 

        // !! setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setText(value.getNameEl());
        // !! list.setVisibleRowCount(30);
        // !! list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 17));

        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            // TODO: fix!
            // setBackground(getBackground());
            // setForeground(getForeground());
            setBackground(null);
            setForeground(null);
        }

        if (value.getOrderRead()) {
            setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        if (value.getOrderDone()) {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return this;
    }

}

class Order {

    private String nameE1;
    private boolean orderDone;
    private boolean orderRead;

    public Order(String nameE1) {
        this.nameE1 = nameE1;
    }

    public String getNameEl() {
        return nameE1;
    }

    public boolean getOrderDone() {
        return orderDone;
    }

    public boolean getOrderRead() {
        return orderRead;
    }

    public void setOrderDone(boolean orderDone) {
        this.orderDone = orderDone;
    }

    public void setOrderRead(boolean orderRead) {
        this.orderRead = orderRead;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow there's a lot of new things here... may I ask you if the AbstractAction is related to invokeLater function you used before? Is that the reason why my row colors changes after selecting a new line? I tried again to write it (and I found out that sscce is also a great way to debug forcing me to clean up my code and revise it deeply... was a total mess, I got lost between 20 classes) and now set rows correctly to green but still after selecting a new row. Sorry if i made you waste time, now I've learned of sscce so next time I will definetely use it!

Comment: @A7X: `AbstractAction` is kind of like an `ActionListener` on steroids. It provides the JButton with its listener, and with several other important state fields and functionalities. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` is used to guarantee that code you run is run on the Swing event thread or EDT (event dispatch thread). This is strictly for Swing thread safety, and neither have anything to do with your code not running.

Comment: Got it. I also noticed you used repaint on the list and in particular, you put all the elements that should stay selected inside another arraylist. I think this is another reason why my code didn't work as expected... But I can't do such a thing if i force single selection on the list, is this right? Or won't either affect on getSelectedValueList method?

Comment: @A7X: *"you put all the elements that should stay selected inside another arraylist"* -- no, my code just allowed for multiple selections is all.

Comment: *"Wow there's a lot of new things here... "* Including, I hope, that your post was not 'long' (a part I edited out of the question). You see, both of the examples provided by @HovercraftFullOfEels is an Sscce (where the first 'S' stands for 'short') otherwise known as a [mcve] (& yes, they were also 'Minimal'!).